# `fread` with headers with special characters (latin1) and unusual nested quotes

Tags: r, data.table

I have a latin1 encoded csv-file with nested quotes:

```
Ort;Stra▒e;Bezeichnung
Vienna;Testgasse 1;"Ministerium ""Pestalozzi"""
Graz;Teststra▒e 3;HS
Salzburg;Beispielstra▒e 9;"NMS ""Die Schlauen"""
Vienna;Wolfgang-Stra▒e 7;"Wirtshaus ""Wien III"""
```

Using fread from data.table 1.9.6 gives a wrong special character (ß) in the header while all ß below are correct - the quoted quotes stay "".

```
dat <- fread("latin1quotedat.csv", encoding = "Latin-1")
dat # wrong header, wrong quotes
       Ort         Stra\xdfe                Bezeichnung
1:   Vienna       Testgasse 1 Ministerium ""Pestalozzi""
2:     Graz      Teststraße 3                         HS
3: Salzburg  Beispielstraße 9       NMS ""Die Schlauen""
4:   Vienna Wolfgang-Straße 7     Wirtshaus ""Wien III""
```

Using `read.csv2` from base R everything is as expected:

```
dat1 <- read.csv2("latin1quotedat.csv", encoding = "latin1")
dat1 # ok
       Ort            Straße              Bezeichnung
1   Vienna       Testgasse 1 Ministerium "Pestalozzi"
2     Graz      Teststraße 3                       HS
3 Salzburg  Beispielstraße 9       NMS "Die Schlauen"
4   Vienna Wolfgang-Straße 7     Wirtshaus "Wien III"
```

Maybe there is an option for the quotes (although I didn't find one).
The misinterpreted special character in the header looks like a bug.

The code and an example csv can be found here: https://github.com/nachti/datatable_test.
Clone the repository and run `latin1quotedat.R`.

Gerhard

Comment: Was an oversight on my part.. skipped the header while implementing the feature. Could you please file this on the project page? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now fixed with [commit f91bba1](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/f91bba11dfd6a1465d7cf80696410fe167ab5952) in [current devel, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> `fread()` did not respect encoding on header column. Now fixed, [#1680](https://github.com/rdatatable/data.table/issues/1680). Thanks @nachti.

With this, I get:

```
names(fread("~/Downloads/latin1quotedat.csv", encoding = "Latin-1"))
# [1] "Ort"         "Straße"      "Bezeichnung"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Arun! Do you have a solution for the quotes as well?

Comment: Solution is straightforward, but most likely in the next release, not sure.